# TextView with a cursor

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to create a custom TextView which should have a cursor.I don't want to use EditText since the input **should not be provided via the android keyboard**, moreover it should look like a TextView.

I've found that the TextView Interface has a support for a cursor, but I was unable to make it show. here is what I've tried:

added

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
```

called

```
textView.setCursorVisible(true);
textView.setSelected(true);
textView.forceLayout();
textView.moveCursorToVisibleOffset();
```

when I added `android:editable="true"` and called `textView.moveCursorToVisibleOffset();` NullPointerException was thrown within the textView.

any suggestions?

Comment: @null would mean it doesn't have a cursor, wouldn't it ?

Comment: it means that the color of the cursor is as the color of the text, anyway I've tried, with and without it.

Comment: have you tried an actual color ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Edit Text like this it shows like Text view:

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@null"/>
```

Comment: "the input should not be provided via the android keyboard"

Comment: For that add one line android:focusable="false"